# VBA - Rename module

Tags: excel, vba

How can we rename a module in a VBA project  under Office 2010 ?

The right click to the module does not offer the ability to do the renaming.

Thanks

Comment: Select it in the Project window and change the name in the Properties window.

Comment: It works thank you, can you post an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you click on the module in the Project Explorer, the name should appear in the properties window (below). It should say "(name) Module1". You can just click on the name there and edit it.

Comment: if properties is not showing then view menu -> properties window.  alternatively press f4

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure you have the **Properties Window** open, if not:

- **MAC**: go to the `view` tab above and then click on `Properties Window`
- **WINDOWS**: just press `F4`

2. Change the name by clicking on the **Module** of preference and then type your desire name in the **Properties Window**:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness a pure VBA solution:

```
Sub RenameModule(wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal oldModuleName As String, _
    ByVal newModuleName As String)
    wb.VBProject.VBComponents(oldModuleName).Name = newModuleName
End Sub
```

which might be called from another opened workbook e.g. as follows:

```
RenameModule Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsm"), "Module1", "RenamedModule"
```

or if the code module to be changed resides in the same workbook:

```
RenameModule ThisWorkbook, "Module1", "RenamedModule"
```

If you prefer shortness you could enter e.g. `ThisWorkbook.VBComponents("Module1").Name = "RenamedModule"` directly into the VB Editor's immediate window.